# HttpWebRequest - sending file by chunks and tracking progress

Tags: c#, http, sockets, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I have the following code that uploads the file to the server by making the POST request:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Console_sk.txt";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Upload");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

Stream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
request.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;

Stream serverStream  = request.GetRequestStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (true)
{
    int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        serverStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);     
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

serverStream.Close();
fileStream.Close();

request.GetResponse();
```

This will be used to upload potentially large files, therefore it is essential for us to track the progress of this upload.

Based on [various sources](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/netfxnetcom/thread/6ead3249-c31b-49b5-bded-8ea182b81607), I've thought that my code will upload file in 4096 byte chunks i.e. multiple POST requests will be made. But when tracking requests by using Fiddler, it shows that only one POST request is made. On other hand, when I enabled [.NET network tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx), the resulting log showed that 4096 byte chunks are indeed written to request stream and the socket is always being opened for each write operation.

My understanding of networking in general is quite poor, so I don't quite understand how this really works. When calling `serverStream.Write`, is the provided chunk really sent over the network, or is it just buffered somewhere? And when `serverStream.Close` is called, can I be sure that the whole file has been uploaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpWebRequest` class sends a **single** HTTP request. What you are doing is that you are writing to the request in chunks to avoid loading the whole file in memory. You are reading from the file and directly writing to the request stream in chunks of 4KB.

> When calling serverStream.Write, is the provided chunk really sent over the network

Yes, it is written to the network socket.

Comment: Thanks for that. What about my second question regarding `serverStream.Close`?

Comment: When you close the request stream, all the data will be written to the socket. Actually you shouldn't be closing those IDisposable resources manually as you did. You should wrap them in `using` statements to ensure proper disposal even in the even of an error.

Comment: Hm, now I am confused again :). At first, you wrote that the chunk is written to the socket when `Write` is called. Now, you say that all data will be written to the socket when `Close` is called. I would be really grateful if you could explain it all in simpler terms, there is probably something I am still missing. Thanks for bearing with me here!

Comment: You are calling .Close at the end. After all Writes have been called multiple times inside your while loop. So at the moment you are calling .Close there's nothing left to write to the socket because you have already written everything. But as I said - you shouldn't be calling .Close manually. You should be wrapping IDisposable resources such as streams in `using` statements. Also if you are using .NET 4.0 you could replace your entire while loop with a single line of code: `fileStream.CopyTo(serverStream, 4096);`.