# I have httpwebrequest object, want to upload it in parts

Tags: c#, http, httpwebresponse

I have below code in a third party function, it posts file to a webserver. I want to post data in parts, what change should i do in the code. Below code is working and the "request" object contains everything.

```
private static HttpWebResponse GetRawResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
{
return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

Also is there a way in which I can find out what is the full name (with path) of the file which is going to be uploaded from the httpwebrequest object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpWebRequest` does not spawn multiple HTTP requests. You cannot upload a file in chunks unless you actually create multiple HttpWebRequests. I don't think that would be useful unless you have a server side process to stitch them back together.

If you still want true chunked uploading you might want to look at raw TCP or some other mechanism.

Hope that helps. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188054/httpwebrequest-sending-file-by-chunks-and-tracking-progress) as well.